# How to troubleshoot slow web page

Tags: networking, apache-http-server, website, dynamic-dns

I have a web page https running on a raspberry pi. When I access it through my LAN by IP, everything works as expected.

I have an address using ddns that I was planning to use, and apache is set up to use it, and I have a cert for the address.
It works, but barely. It is really slow, making it unusable.

I don't know how to troubleshoot why the connection is slow. Any pointers?

Comment: http URL works fine http @WAN works fine. https at LAN works fine, but not at WAN or URL. So apparently something going on with the router using https. Not sure what else to try.

Comment: Don't add a comment, edit your post to add relevant info.

How slow is slow?

Answer (score 1):

Is Apache set to log page requests where the logged data includes the DNS name of the browser? Misconfigured DNS is often a cause of surprisingly long delays at the server end in other protocols as the DNS lookups timeout.

Otherwise I'd use a network sniffer like Wireshark to get better insight. If the response is OK inside the LAN, it probably wouldn't be a problem within Apache. Nevertheless, the Apache logs would be worth looking at.